# Adding multiple JIRAs to a sprint

Tags: jira

Does anyone know if it is possible to add multiple jiras to a sprint in one operation. Consider I do a search for a particular label I have on my backlog jiras. I then want to add all of these to the next sprint. Is this possible or do I have to do it one by one

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you using Greenhopper and you are on the **`Agile`** screen you can do it like [mdoar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123802/mdoar) said and using [Shift] or [Ctrl] to select multiple issues. If you start dragging them a small red circle appears indicating how much issues you are about to move to your sprint.

---

As you did not clearly state, that you are using Greenhopper/Agile, there is another way:

**You can use the issue navigator and bulk edit all those issues and edit the sprint field.**

Therefor you click on **`Tools`** on the top right of your issue search result and select *`all xy issues`*. Then you will be forwarded to the buld edit page. There you select the issues you want to edit or simply check the first check box to select all isues. Then you select *`Next`* and *`Edit Issues`*. Scroll down and check *`Edit Sprint`* and enter the Sprint you want those issues to be added to. Check if you want to receive a notification via Email for that bulk edit. Click *`Next`* and *`Apply`* to apply your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select multiple issues to drag into a sprint using the usual click, move the mouse, shift click, or however you would select multiple values in your OS and browser